# Unable to concatenate strings into excel countifs OR criteria

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I'm trying to utilize the syntax for `OR` like criteria for a `COUNTIFS` function in Excel. However, when trying use cell references, it just tells me

> There is a problem with this formula

Function: `=SUM(COUNTIFS(rosterTable[lastDayWithClient], {">="&A7,""}))`

Specifically if I'm trying to use `&A7` to concatenate the criteria with a cell value, it fails.

Comment: This may be one of those times you need to split into two countif and add them together: `=COUNTIFS(rosterTable[lastDayWithClient], ">="&A7) + COUNTIFS(rosterTable[lastDayWithClient], "")`

Comment: Array constants can contain numbers, text, logical values (such as TRUE and FALSE), and error values.  `">="&A7` is not an allowed entry in an array constant.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Gotcha, that's too bad. Excel is really starting to fall behind on some features you see in online spreadsheet applications. Thanks for the info. Please post that as an answer if there is a source people can reference to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`">="&A7` is not an allowed entry in an array constant.

Per Excel Help:  `Array constants can contain numbers, text, logical values (such as TRUE and FALSE), and error values.`

As @ScottCraner indicated, you can accomplish the same by summing separate COUNTIF functions.  The `AGGREGATE` function, or various types of `SUMPRODUCT` implementations may also provide a solution.